# Can mathematica be configured to auto pair different parenthese?

Tags: autocomplete, editing

In [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/), the editor can auto pair different parentheses, for example code like `(let [(x 3` and whether press `)` or `]` key will input the correct type of parentheses `)`, and the next `)` will produce `]`. So it can match the correct type of parentheses of the expression.

Does Mathematica has the same functionality, or can configure the same thing somewhere?

Comment: Doctor who ?  :D

Comment: @belisarius Doctor? DrRacket ? ?_?